# How can we filter out personal information from "journalctl"?

Tags: security, systemd, systemd-journald

I was wondering if there was a way to filter out personal information when collecting system information with `journalctl`. Can we, for example, remove MAC/IP addresses, certificates, firmware keys, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Many of the items you mention aren't worth concealing, or aren't logged.

Does your firewall or router do NAT (Network Address Translation)? Everybody's got `192.168.*.*` IPs, so there is no benefit to concealing yours.

MAC addresses, by Standard, are visible only on your LAN. Nobody outside your LAN can access via MAC. MAC Addresses do encode some manufacturer information, so it's good to report.

Other info, "certificates, and firmware keys": Secret data is NOT logged (or it's a bug).

Other info, "etc." If it's secret and it's logged it's a bug.

Report bugs via the `ubuntu-bug` command.

Back in the old days, I used multiple `sed` (`man sed`) expressions, or specially written Perl scripts (`man perl`, buy the Camel book "Programming Perl"). Use standard GNU/Linux tools, e.g.: `journalctl ... | grep -v 'Secret='` will hide secrets.

Before you put a lot of effort into hiding information in `journalctl` output, verify that the information is logged.

Perform a Threat/Risk Analysis. What, exactly, is the Threat? What's the Risk if the Threat comes to pass? What's the Risk of protecting against the threat (Powering down prevents all Threats, but ...). What's the cost? Must the protection be constantly re-done, or is a fix-once?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @tla I've "improved" my answer.  Does this help?